# Can't execute Android Emulator in Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-emulator

I've made an Android emulator in Android Virtual Devices Manager, but when I try to open it I get the following message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android40'
Could not launch '/home/andy/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator-arm': Permission denied".
```

How can I fix it? My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: try running the emulator from shell.

Comment: Please type `ls -l ~/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-arm` and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the jdk.
The following link might be useful: 
http://antonis.se/?p=40

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
```

You will have to choose the 32/64 bit version appropriately